# Prevent generating Rplot.emf when a function using ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

I have written a function to serve as a wrapper around `ggsave()` to save plots as an EMF (for use with PowerPoint).

```
emf_save <- function(ggp) {
  filename <- glue::glue("{here()}",
                         "/",
                         "{deparse(substitute(ggp))}.emf")
  
  ggsave(
    plot = ggp,
    filename = filename,
    height = 5.2,
    width = 11.5,
    units = "in",
    device = devEMF::emf()
  )
  
  dev.off()
  print(paste0("Saved ", filename))
}
```

It accepts a ggplot2 object and saves an EMF file with the object's name. The problem is, whenever I call this function, it also saves a file called Rplot.emf in the project folder.

How do I prevent this file generation?

Comment: Hmm, so far I can reproduce the problem with a png if I use `device = png()`.  But not if I use `device = "png"`.

Comment: Oh, I think I see.  Try using `device = devEMF::emf` instead of `device = devEMF::emf()`.

Comment: @aosmith That's probably it. When I use `devEMF::emf()` the function executes. I'll give it a try and close the question if it is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: That didn't work; removing the parentheses broke the function. It did, however, prevent the Rplot.emf file from being generated. The error it gave was: `Error in dev(filename = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...) : 
  unused argument (filename = filename)`

Comment: Is your ggplot2 version up to date?  I think there was an issue about this (file vs filename) that has been fixed.  It worked for me using devEMF with a current version of ggplot2.  [This](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3807) is the issue that I thought might be relevant.

Comment: I updated, and the error persists. `#> ggplot2     * 3.3.2   2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)`

Comment: Switching to using `device = devEMF::emf` works for me without error on Windows 7 R 4.0.0 with ggplot2 3.3.2 and doesn't save the extra Rplot.emf plot.  I hope you figure it out!